# Django disable trailing slash

Tags: django

I'm using Django 2.0.6 (using the development server for now) and am having issues with automatic trailing slashes being appended to URL's.

My goal is to have a URL structure as follows:

- /teams/ => Index view for all teams
- /teams/create => Form view to create a new team (note the lack of trailing slash)
- /teams/xyz/ => Index view for team with slug xyz
- /teams/xyz/delete => Form view to delete team xyz (require confirmation, etc)

The problem is that, somewhere in Django framework, a trailing slash is automatically being appended to 'create' URL's. Because of this, the router the attempts to load the team index page for a team with slug 'create'. Obviously, a workaround would be to stop using slugs and use ID's, but that seems like an unnecessary concession.

Looking around, it seems that setting [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) to False should tell CommonMiddleware to stop appending slashes, but this didn't help.

Is there a way to easily accomplish my URL scheme and, if not, what's the idiomatic Django way to do this?

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('<slug:team_slug>/', views.view, name='view'),
    path('<slug:team_slug>/invite/', views.invite, name='invite')
]
```

settings.py:

```
APPEND_SLASH = False

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',   
]
```

Links are correctly generated with the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'teams:create' %}">New Team</a>
```

Which translates to: `/teams/create`

However, when the user clicks the link, it appears to be immediately redirected to `/teams/create/`

Comment: Can you clarify, is it that a link is being generated which includes an extra trailing slash, or is it that you type in the slash-less URL and you are being redirected to one with a slash? If the former, can you show an example of a template that includes the link?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : The link is generated correctly without the slash in my template code, but when you follow the link you're immediately redirected to the same URL with the trailing slash appended. Once there, if you delete the slash from the URL and go to the page manually, you're once again redirected. I've updated the question.

Comment: The strange thing is that even with APPEND_SLASH as True, the CommonMiddleware will only redirect if there is no match without the slash. So it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a directory named `common` in your project directory.
- Create `__init__.py` and `redirect.py` in `common` directory.

  ```
  # redirect.py

  from django.conf import settings
  from django.core import urlresolvers
  from django import http

  '''
  Based on django/middleware/common.py

  Django convention is to add trailing slashes to most urls
  This method does the opposite and redirects trailing slashes to the
  no trailing slash url if it exists
  '''
  class RedirectTrailingSlashMiddleware(object):

      def process_request(self, request):
          if settings.APPEND_SLASH:
              return 

      if '/admin' in request.path:
          settings.APPEND_SLASH = True         
          return

      new_url = old_url = request.path

      if (old_url.endswith('/')):
          urlconf = getattr(request, 'urlconf', None)
          if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
              urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info[:-1], urlconf)):
              new_url = new_url[:-1]
              if settings.DEBUG and request.method == 'POST':
                  raise RuntimeError((""
                  "You called this URL via POST, but the URL ends "
                  "in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't "
                  "redirect to the non-slash URL while maintaining POST data. "
                  "Change your form to point to %s (note no trailing "
                  "slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=True in your Django "
                  "settings.") % (new_url))

      if new_url == old_url:
          # No redirects required.
          return

      return http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(new_url)
  ```
- In your `settings.py`, add:

  ```
  MIDDLEWARE = [
      'common.redirect.RedirectTrailingSlashMiddleware',
      # Add as first element
  ]
  ```

Source/credit: http://bunwich.blogspot.com/2013/06/django-change-trailing-slash-url.html